# Обороты с "такой же"/" такой как"

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот, определения

> А он, такой же встревоженный, встал с кресла и тихим шагом подошёл к окну.

> В тот раз я видел красивый цветок, такой же синий, как небо.

> Письма, такого, как в тот раз, я более не получал.

Скажите, пожалуйста, в данных примерах обособленные конструкции являются обособленными определениями? Верна ли пунктуация, особенно в последнем случае? Вроде бы никаких предпосылок к отсутствию запятой перед "как" нет. Сравнительный оборот распространяет определение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, там везде обособленные определения.

Третий пример правильный, другие тоже.

`Как в тот раз` - это сравнение. Там обязательны обе запятые.

Другое дело, что в третьем примере можно и без запятой перед `такого`. Но если добавить прилагательное, которое есть во втором примере, то без запятой уже нельзя:

`Интересного письма, такого, как в тот раз, я более не получал.`

По этой же причине запятую можно не ставить после `он`. Но там намного лучше с запятой по контексту, так как `А он | встал с кресла` - эти элементы очень связаны, а между ними обособленная конструкция.

Это также зависит от логических пауз при чтении, намерений автора отделить определения.

Однозначно обособленным определение является тогда, когда перед существительным присутствуют другие определения (чего нет в примерах №1 и №3).

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ. Хочу внести окончательную ясность по вопросу. Действительно, запятые поставлены в соответствии с замыслом автора и паузами. Вся проблема именно в том, что указательные местоимения крайне редко обособляются, а если обособляются, то по замыслу автора и конструкции предложения. В качестве примера можно привести песню Розенбаума "Камикадзе" со словами "Весь мой долгий путь до цели, той, которая в прицеле". Но здесь, по моему мнению, два момента: 1. Можно сказать, что придаточные все же относится к указательному местоимению (другой вариант - к " цели той"), распространяя его

Comment: 2. Возможен различный смысл, который влияет на предложение. Представим ситуацию. Вы сидите с другом в кафе, и мимо вас проходит девушка. Вы скажете другу 'Девушка та, которая прошла, весьма красивая.' Известно из ситуации, о ком идёт разговор - указывается ТА, конкретная девушка. Даже придаточное, возможно, излишне. Другая ситуация: вы сидите, мимо вас проходят три девушки в разной одежде. Вы скажете 'Девушка, та, которая в синем, весьма красива.' Внимание не сосредоточено на одной девушке, которую можно указать. Но я не исключают различного толкования даже в этом случае. На все воля автора.

Comment: Согласен, что в песне 2 варианта. Как и говорил, это зависит от логических пауз. Но необособленные определения очень неестественно звучат после существительных, особенно если дальше идёт уточняющая конструкция. Проблема в том, что если оборот будет относится ко всей фразе, то корректно говорить "до той цели, которая", "та девушка, которая". А наоборот - это стилистическая ошибка (то, что плохо звучит), хоть и не грамматическая. Сомневаюсь, что можно найти "звучащие" примеры. Но это может быть уместно в стихах, где всё ради рифмы. Меня этот вопрос тоже заинтересовал, поэтому ставлю вам лайк.